# How to change Shell path globally in IntelliJ IDEA Community 2020.2?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

I just recently updated my IntelliJ IDEA to 2020.2 (on Windows; build from July, 27th). What's driving me crazy is that now all my projects use the default path `cmd.exe` at Settings > Terminal > Shell Path.

Before the update, I have set `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` there once and it was fine with all my projects.

Now, whenever I open a project for the first time after the update, I have to reconfigure this setting. I haven't found a way yet to configure this globally once and for all, like it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 where the IDE will only use the project-level path for WSL shells. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247113 for more information.